# Open an HTML Document with xml.Load

Tags: c#, html, xml, document

I'd like to open an HTML document (as a string retrieved from a StreamReader, from the web), 
by creating a XMLDocument this way:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument

doc.Load(string containing the retrieved document).
```

But since the HTML doc contains this head:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
```

It tells me that the document is invalid... Any way to workaround this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal html, even if it's valid html, is not valid xml.

There is a library called HtmlAgilityPack which is a popular 3rd party open source library that you can use to solve this problem:

- http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=htmlagilitypack
- [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack/2588910)

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive that the HTML is valid XML, I imagine you could simply replace the HTML head with an XML one.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to validate that the XHTML is a valid XHTML document (it means that is a valid XML document too).

paste your XHTML code here and review the output.
http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

good luck!.

Answer (score 0):

One can use HTML Tidy [Tidy.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/) for this.